# How to expand dataset based on categories in SAS? (For loop?)

Tags: sas

First off, apologies for the vague title, but I don't really know how to phrase what I'm asking. I have a SAS dataset that gives me unit ID, job ID, and the number of employees in that unit-job combination for each of several wage bands (ie, for unit 1, job A, there are 3 employees in band A, 2 employees in band B, etc.). I want to blow this up so that I have a single employee in each row in order to measure dispersion, variance, mean, median, etc. Below is an example of what I have and what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

What I have:

```
data have;
length id1 id2 $20;
infile datalines dlm=' ';
input id1 $ id2 $ a  b  c ;
datalines;
123 A1 2 1 0
123 A2 0 1 1
123 A3 1 0 0
456 A1 0 3 0
456 A2 1 1 1
456 A3 1 2 1
;
```

What I want to turn it into:

```
                                  ID1    IDS    Category

                                  123    A1       A
                                  123    A1       A
                                  123    A1       B
                                  123    A2       B
                                  123    A2       C
                                  123    A3       A
                                  456    A1       B
                                  456    A1       B
                                  456    A1       B
                                  456    A2       A
                                  456    A2       B
                                  456    A2       C
                                  456    A3       A
                                  456    A3       B
                                  456    A3       B
                                  456    A3       C
```

Comment: I doubt that you need to "blow up your data".  Most PROCs support a FREQ statement or if you're using PROC FREQ you would use WEIGHT with the / ZEROS option.

Comment: Thanks so much. When I assign values to each band, how can I get mean, median and standard deviation at the unit-job level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that you will find a better solution, I can't figure out which is really the result that you want to get.
Anyway, the requested dataset could be derived with a pair of nested do loops:

```
data prova;
length id1 id2 a b c $20;
infile datalines dlm=' ';
input id1 $ id2 $ a $ b $ c $;
datalines;
123 A1 2 1 0
123 A2 0 1 1
123 A3 1 0 0
456 A1 0 3 0
456 A2 1 1 1
456 A3 1 2 1
;

data prova01;
length category $20;
set prova;

array ncats[*] a b c;
array chcats[*] $ ac bc cc ('a' 'b' 'c');

do i=1 to dim(ncats);
do j=1 to ncats[i];
category=chcats[i];
output;
end;
end;

drop i j ac bc cc a b c;
run;
```

Comment: Instead of a second array consider using the VNAME() function to obtain the column name, then you don't need to know it ahead of time. It may also be helpful to read in ABC as numerics.

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much!